# System.StringException thrown when aborting a job in a rest controller

Tags: apex, rest-api, scheduled-apex, string

This code works in an Execute Anonymous window, but not when run from a rest controller:

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/scheduler')
    global with sharing class SchedulerController {

    @HttpDelete
    global static String stopPusher(){
        List<CronTrigger> triggers = [SELECT CronTrigger.Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE State = 'WAITING'  and CronJobDetail.Name Like 'Ambition%' ];
        if(triggers.size() == 0){
            return 'no jobs running';
        }
        String id =  triggers[0].id;
        System.abortJob(id);
        System.debug(id);
        return 'aborted ' + id;
    }}
```

I get the following response from the controller:

> [{"message":"System.StringException: entityId : U#224.3fffffff (CronJobDetail)\n\nClass.ambition.SchedulerController.stopPusher: line 11, column 1","errorCode":"APEX_ERROR"}]
>   500

What is going on here?

I am calling the endpoint with the following python code:

```
url = 'https://na15.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/ambition/scheduler'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
r = requests.delete(url, headers=headers) 
print r.text
print r.status_code
```

Comment: I can execute that code snipper just fine, could it be that you've not included enough code ? Error also indicates some controller method..

Comment: Yes, please can you share the entire signature and return type? Have you obfuscated the exception message?

Comment: I will update the code snippet to include the controller. I did edit the error, but didn't think that was important. Line 14 is the System.abortJob(id); call.

Comment: Am I glad I stumbled upon this error, thanks for posting, it saved me some hours of searching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As rao said, there is a [SF known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SyhIAAS) preventing jobs from being aborted in a custom rest controller.

Here is a simplified version of my job's execute method:

```
    public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        //configUtil.getState() retrieves the custom setting with the 'RUNNING'/'STOPPED' state information.
        if(configUtil.getState() != 'RUNNING'){
            //abort the current job, and return.
            System.abortJob( SC.getTriggerId() );
            return;
        }

        //do stuff
        coolMethodThatDoesCoolStuff();

        //reschedule job to run again in 1 minute
        Datetime sysTime = System.now().addSeconds(60);      
        String chronExpression = '' + sysTime.second() + ' ' + sysTime.minute() + ' ' + sysTime.hour() + ' ' + sysTime.day() + ' ' + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();
        System.schedule( 'AmbitionPusherSelfSchedule' + sysTime, chronExpression, new Pusher() );
        //abort the current job instead of running again in an hour.
        System.abortJob( SC.getTriggerId() );
    }
```

and here is the code from the controller:

```
@HttpDelete
global static String stop(){
    configUtil.setState('STOPPED');
    return 'job stop requested';
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to the world of known issues :

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SyhIAAS

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I will schedule a job to delete the other job as a way to work around this issue. In the mean time, this is how I feel right now: http://www.memes.at/faces/whyyy.jpg

Comment: actually, I ended up using a custom setting that the job checks before it runs. If the settings says 'stop', then it does not execute, and unschedules itself; if it says 'run', then it runs normally. the rest endpoint now manipulates this custom setting instead of trying to abort the job.

Comment: That's a sleek workaround. Post your comment as an answer and mark your answer as solved.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this is triggered by [a known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SyhIAAS).

A different workaround is to use SOAP instead of REST.